# FFT channelising for DF

Tags: fft, sampling, array-signal-processing

I have a 25 MHz IBW real time signal analyser throwing out 25 MHz wide complex data at 50 MHz sampling frequency.
I want the frequency resolution to be 12.5 kHz (width of a vhf channel) so need 2000 (2048 pt FFT).
Since I'm sampling @50 MHz, i have 50000 samples per millisecond.
It's it the right approach to calculate a 2K FFT over 50k samples, or should i chunk the data into 2048 sample chunks, ie ~50us?
Does it reduce my compute operations?

Comment: is IBW = instantaneous bandwidth?

Comment: you need 2000, not 2048.

Comment: (the fact that power-of-2 FFTs are especially efficient to compute doesn't mean they suit any particular purpose. Your bandwidth is 12.5 kHz, not 12.20703125 kHz. Don't worry, 2000-point-FFTs are still relatively performant.)

Comment: "It's it the right approach to calculate a 2K FFT over 50k samples" A 2000 point FFT has exactly 2000 input samples. There's no such thing as calculating a $N$-point FFT over $M$ samples, $M\ne N$. Maybe you're trying to describe Bartlett's method?